# Filter spark Dataframe with specific timestamp literal

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have to filter records in dataframe with all records greater than a specific timestamp.

My timestamp column in dataframe is in string format.

```
Name DOJ
---------
Ram  01-Jan-2000 00.00.00.001 AM
Tom  01-Jan-2020 00.00.00.001 AM
Ali  01-Jan-2010 00.00.00.001 AM

df.PrintSchema
Name|--String
DOJ |--String
```

I need to filter all records which are greater than ("01-Jan-2005 00.00.00.001 AM")

Everything is in String Format

I tried various ways but results are not consistent it seems it comparing string. Probably I am facing issues in converting literal to timestamp and getting variable results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot compare time when it is in string. Pyspark offers a api to convert strings to timestamp : https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=to_timestamp#pyspark.sql.functions.to_timestamp
With this you will be able to convert your column as a dateType and then can do comparisions.

Try it out.

In your case, you are using the 12 hour format (hh), here the allowed values are 1-12 as per SimpleDateFormat that spark uses. Refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

So if you need a 24 hour format change the hour string to HH

Since you are giving 00 to the hh, it is becoming invalid. The below code works . Also careful about the format you give and the string format. if there is a mismatch then you get null.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

tst=sqlContext.createDataFrame([('Ram','01-Jan-2000 01.00.00.001 AM'),('Tom','01-Jan-2020 11.00.00.001 AM'),('Ali',' 01-Jan-2010 07.00.00.001 AM')],schema=["Name","DOJ"])
tst1=tst.withColumn("ts",F.to_timestamp(F.col("DOJ"),format="dd-MMM-yyyy hh.mm.ss.SSS aa"))
#%%
tst2 =tst1.filter(F.col('ts')>F.to_timestamp(F.lit("01-Jan-2005 01.00.00.001 AM"),format="dd-MMM-yyyy hh.mm.ss.SSS aa"))
```

results :

```
|Name|DOJ                         |ts                 |
+----+----------------------------+-------------------+
|Tom |01-Jan-2020 11.00.00.001 AM |2020-01-01 11:00:00|
|Ali | 01-Jan-2010 07.00.00.001 AM|2010-01-01 07:00:00|
+----+----------------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: I already tries using to_timestamp. . .. but somehow i feel literal date that I am passing is not getting convert in timestamp

Comment: it should.. can you post a sample code of what you tried? also with a sample data and code to reproduce it

Comment: df.filter(to_timestamp(DOJ,"dd-MMM-yyyy hh.mm.ss.SSS aaa").gt(to_timestamp("01-Jan-2005 00.00.00.001 AM","dd-MMM-yyyy hh.mm.ss.SSS aaa")))

Comment: are you getting any error message? can you be clear about the problem?

Comment: to add above query works fine in hive but with spark its not

Comment: its the problem in the string format - use HH instead of hh. see my updated answer

Comment: Hi I even tired replacing with HH but still results are inconsistent ..and since I am having AM/PM in format that mean it has to be in 12 Hr Format.

Comment: If you use hh, you cannot have 00 in your hour..did you check this? Refer the code in my answer. .I had changed the hour values from 00 to something else.. like 01

Comment: Yes I am getting this from upper system so its coming in valid without 00 in hh

Comment: can you check the updated answer showing the filtering? are you doing it like this?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts this it was an environment issue and also the date format

Comment: happy to hear :-)